# Print Empty Message if Array is Empty

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Assuming I want to print the array in reverse order. However if the array is empty it should print "The array is empty"

Why does this code Not Work:

Can we assume that if the array is empty `a.length` is 0 or is it null?
What should a.length be == in the if() statement.what is wrong with the if statement in the for loop that doesn't allow it to work? Or did it never enter the for loop?

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {};

        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
            if (a.length == 0)
                System.out.print("The array is empty");

        }
    }
}
```

This Code works:

```
if (a.length == 0)
    System.out.print("The array is empty");
else
{
    for(int i = a.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        System.out.print (a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

And this works too:

```
for(int i = a.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    System.out.print (a[i] + " ");
}
if (a.length == 0)
    System.out.print("The array is empty");
```

Comment: if you are using java, please add it to the tags.

Comment: Please specify a language

Comment: In your first section of code the line `if (a.length == 0)` is _within_ your `for` loop (unlike the other two sections). The array length will never be zero inside the loop, so you do not get the output you seek.

Comment: dave you stated the array length will never be zero inside the loop. if the array begin as being empty ... or does it means you can never make an array that has no element in it. Therefore,  an array always have to have a length of 1 or more length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `int[] a = {};`creates an array of size 0. hence for loop does not even execute in the first case. Let's see the second case.

Here , if condition `if (a.length == 0)` gets executed and else part does not.

Lets see the third case. Again for loop does not execute. Next code moves to if statement which is outside the for loop. It gets executed.

I hope you understand why your for loop does not execute. See `a.length=0`. hence `i =-1` but the condition that we give in for loop is `i>=0`

Comment: thanks Breaking Benjamin! you help me discover why it will never work.  My understanding is  since:  i = a.length - 1  and i being 0 for an empty array, it would never enter the for loop b/c i would be -1.  And even if we change it to :  for(int i = a.length ; i >= a.length ; i--) when it  minus-minus it becomes outOfBound.  Great!